# Getting error in sigin through firebase in my app

Tags: firebase-authentication, android-studio-4.1

.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" But I also recommend having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the text field was not assigned before trying to access it, please refer to the relevant documentation for accessing and assigning text fields and their values. More debugging is needed to sufficiently answer anything else.

Comment: Ok thanks now it is working after adding a non null exception quote...